# Someone is sending FB messages that appear to come from my android! HOW?

Tags: security, privacy

We recently had a house guest who asked to use my phone. She is sending Facebook messages drom her Android phone that appear to be coming from me! This is causing serious problems! I want to catch her. I suspect she has also stolen items that could be used for identity theft. My device is an unlocked LG. I don't have a carrier, I just use our Wi-Fi. Her phone is also an LG through Boost Mobile. Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Change your FB password ASAP

Answer (score 0):

> Just do a system format she might have installed things onto your
>   phone, make sure to back up things you need. reset your phone by:
>   **1. powering it down.
>    2. Hold the power button + Home button + Volume down button (Together and hold until you see  light).
>    3. Use the volume keys to move up and down and the power button to select options.
>    4. Locate wipe data/factory reset (use volume keys to go to it and use power button to select it).
>    5. you will see a confirmation to confirm the factory reset use the volume keys to go to yes and press the power button to select it.
>    6. wait for it to complete then select reboot system now.
>    7. done.
>    8.  (also change your facebook password just to be safe).**

[image]

Comment: How does wiping the OP's phone stop another person from using that account on a different phone?